# How does Pfizer vaccine affect covid test?

Tags: united-states, vaccine, covid

Medical question on possible outcomes of tests. **Assuming patient does NOT have actual covid. Perfectly Healthy**

1. A patient gets a Pfizer vaccine first dose today. Will the patient’s Covid nose swab test come out positive or negative if the patient takes the test tomorrow? What if the patient  waits 7 days? Will  Covid test come out positive or negative?
2. A patient gets a Pfizer vaccine second dose today (the first dose was already administered 21 days ago). Will the patient get a negative or positive COVID nose swab test the next day? What about 2 weeks from the second dose?

| Time | Covid Nose Swab Test |
| --- | --- |
| The next day after Pfizer 1st dose | Positive or Negative? |
| One week after Pfizer 1st dose. | Positive or Negative? |
| Two weeks after Pfizer 1st dose | Positive or Negative? |
| One day after Pfizer 2nd dose | Positive or Negative? |
| One week after Pfizer 2nd dose | Positive or Negative? |
| Two weeks after Pfizer 2nd dose | Positive or Negative? |

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is clearly answered by the CDC's ["Myths and Facts about COVID-19 Vaccines"](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/vaccines/facts.html)

> Will getting a COVID-19 vaccine cause me to test positive for COVID-19 on a viral test?
>
> No. None of the authorized and recommended COVID-19 vaccines cause you to test positive on viral tests, which are used to see if you have a current infection.​

Comment: And the reason why it can't happen is that authorized (PCR) tests test for more viral proteins than the spike.